# Good solution to work with rest-api like SPA with redux?

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement admin-site for commenting-system. I have REST-API with JSON.  I don't want do  isomorphic application. I just want feel in Single Page manner. I see there is already has some solutions:

1) Create ajax factory and send request to api methods with XmlHttpRequest, during dispatch action and handling this by hands.

2) Redux-api or redux-rest.

3) Method that used in redux real-world example.

For my job i need's stable solution. I think to choose redux-api. But i don't know which disadvantages can be in each variant.

Maybe anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definitive answer to this; however I am using a variant of [`redux-api-middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware) which allows me to keep my action creators stateless and free of side effects.

redux-api and redux-rest both look valid; if somewhat 'magic' based on the amount of configuration / convention they enforce on your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your option is right for me , as it is very close to the  real-world-example. I can easily read the source code and adapt it in his manner.